# Table view data source array deallocated after handling asynchronous loading of data

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, asynchronous, wsdl2objc

I'm pretty new to Objective-C and am having a problem updating my `UITableView` after an asynchronous call. 
I have a table view populated from an `NSMutableArray`; I populate the array from a JSON response from a .net web service.  I'm using `wsdl2objc` to get the JSON from the web service.

Here is my code:

```
@interface NewsViewController : UITableViewController <ServiceSoapBindingResponseDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) News *news;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *newsList;

-(void) updateNewView:(NSMutableArray*) result;
-(void) loadNewsFromRemoteServer;

@end


-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    _newsList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self loadNewsFromRemoteServer];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void) loadNewsFromRemoteServer
{  
    NSString *customerID = @"xxx";
    NSString *uniqueID = @"xxx";    
    ServiceSoapBinding *bNews = [[ServiceSvc ServiceSoapBinding] retain];
    bNews.logXMLInOut = YES;
    ServiceSvc_GetNews *cRequest = [[ServiceSvc_GetNews new] autorelease];
    cRequest.id_ = customerID;
    cRequest.uniqueId = uniqueID;
    [bNews GetNewsAsyncUsingParameters:cRequest delegate:self];
}


-(void) operation:(ServiceSoapBindingOperation *)operation completedWithResponse:(ServiceSoapBindingResponse *)response
{
    NSArray *responseHeaders = response.headers;
    NSArray *responseBodyParts = response.bodyParts;
    NSMutableArray *newsListFromWebserver = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(id header in responseHeaders) {
        // here do what you want with the headers, if there's anything of value in them
    }
    for(id bodyPart in responseBodyParts) {         
        if ([bodyPart isKindOfClass:[SOAPFault class]]) {
            // You can get the error like this:
            //NSLog(@"new list :: RESPONSE FROM SERVER :: %@",((SOAPFault *)bodyPart).simpleFaultString);
            continue;
        }
        //Get News List
        if([bodyPart isKindOfClass:[ServiceSvc_GetNewsResponse class]]) {
            ServiceSvc_GetNewsResponse *body = (ServiceSvc_GetNewsResponse*)bodyPart;
            NSString *nList = body.GetNewsResult;  //JSON FORMAT
            NSLog(@"new list :: RESPONSE FROM SERVER :: nList %@", nList);
            NSDictionary *resultsDictionary = [nList objectFromJSONString] ;
            for (NSDictionary * dataDict in resultsDictionary) {
                News *newNews = [[News alloc] init];
                _news = newNews;
                _news.newsTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:[dataDict objectForKey:@"Title"]];
                _news.newsBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:[dataDict objectForKey:@"Body"]];
                _news.newsDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:[dataDict objectForKey:@"NewDate"]];
                [newsListFromWebserver addObject:_news];
               [_news release];
            }    
        }
    }   
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateNewView:) withObject:newsListFromWebserver waitUntilDone:NO];
    [newsListFromWebserver release];
}

-(void) updateNewView:(NSMutableArray*) result
{
    _newsList = result;
    NSLog( @"new list - number of news :: %u", [_newsList count]);
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";   
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }    
     cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    //Get the object from the array.
    News *cNews = [_newsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = cNews.newsDate;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = cNews.newsTitle;
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bullet.png"];        
    return cell;
}
```

My application logs this to the console:

```
2012-09-08 22:36:45.463 xxx[45630:13a03] new list - number of news :: 1
2012-09-08 22:36:45.465 xxx[45630:13a03] *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x79a3680
```

It fails calling `[_newsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.
Any help? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using ARC? Are you using auto-synthesized properties?

Comment: I'm not using ARC and yes I'm using @synthesize in m. file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time `updateNewView:` method is called in the Main Thread `newsListFromWebserver` object created in the `operation:completedWithResponse:` method is released in the last line of that method and hence deallocated. The simplest way to fix the problem is to assign value to `_newsList` ivar inside `operation:completedWithResponse:` and after that call `updateNewView` in the main thread. Notice, that in that case you can remove the `result` argument from it.

Also there is a leak in the first line of `updateNewView` method.

Here is a small hint how it should look like:

```
-(void) operation:(ServiceSoapBindingOperation *)operation completedWithResponse:           (ServiceSoapBindingResponse *)response
{
    // your old parsing code here

    self.newsList = newsListFromWebserver;
    [newsListFromWebserver release];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateNewView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}

-(void) updateNewView
{
    NSLog( @"new list - number of news :: %u", [_newsList count]);
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you are not using ARC. The reason you're crashing then is that you're assigning an autoreleased value to your instance variable and not retaining it:

```
-(void) updateNewView:(NSMutableArray*) result
{
    _newsList = result; // Should release the old and retain the new!
    NSLog( @"new list - number of news :: %u", [_newsList count]);
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Personally I would change your whole program to use the property wherever possible but at the very least you need to release the old value and retain the new

```
-(void) updateNewView:(NSMutableArray*) result
{
    self.newsList = result;
    NSLog( @"new list - number of news :: %u", [_newsList count]);
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Such change will definitely help with memory leaking, but still cannot guarantee that value passed to `updateNewView` is not deallocated already.

Comment: Ah, did not see that was not the callback. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the program to use ARC. i've tried both the solutions here .. but nothing .. the value is still deallocated

Comment: @ellie, you should replace
`[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateNewView:) withObject:newsListFromWebserver waitUntilDone:NO];`

with

`self.newsList = newsListFromWebserver;
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateNewView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];`

You should also replace `updateNewView:` with `updateNewView` method which won't accept any arguments, and please also replace the first line of the old `updateNewView:` method.

Comment: I've updated my answer to make it more clear, please check it.

Comment: @ellie you should also ensure, that you are not overloading `setNewsList` method incorrectly (without keeping it's retain nature).

Comment: @Dmitry. I've replaced the code as you said:
now I have
self.newsList = newsListFromWebserver;
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateNewView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
    [newsListFromWebserver release];

and
- (void) updateNewView
{    
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


It seems like now the newlist array is not empty or deallocated anymore but I get a new error message saying
-[CFString isEqualToString:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7874fa0
in line
 cell.textLabel.text = cNews.newsDate;

Comment: @ellie it sounds like you have some significant issues with memory management in your application. Make sure to read the official [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html) [Documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) (two links there!) on memory management, and use the tools described in the second article to analyze and debug your application.

Comment: @Dmitry: thanks a lot! your solution and your suggestions worked perfectly. I had a couple of issues in retain properties in the News model I've created .. the last problem wasn't in the UITableViewController but in the model itself. Thank you very much for your help!